# Finding theta of two vectors provided A and B.

Tags: vectors

In class today the professor wanted to warm up our minds by reminding us of vectors. The last time I did vectors was five years ago. Moving on, the following was provided:

A is a vector = 3i - 2j

B is a vector = -i + j

I found $\vec A + \vec B$ and other simple equations until I came across this:

$\theta$ = (A, ^B).

what is the ^ sign? And how should I go forwards to finding theta. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: could he have meant $\hat B$ as in the unit vector of B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's meant to be
$$\theta=\widehat {(\vec{A},\vec{B})}$$
and it just means find the angle between the vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.

Answer (score 2):

i thin $^$ is Unit Vector of a given vector and he has wanted $A$ projection to long unit vector of $B$. or if he has used ‎$\langle U, V\rangle$ it means inner product of two vectors.